# C++ getline function continuous loop

Tags: c++

I am trying to use a getline function in the following code, however it just enters an indefinite loop. Should I enter 1, it will then jump to the another iteration of the loop and ask for my menu choice again, rather than asking for my name.

Does anyone have any idea where I'm going wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <ncurses.h>

using namespace std;
// DECLARE

void menu();
void menu_act_on_choice();
void string_function();


// CODE

void menu_act_on_choice(int choice_in) {
    switch (choice_in) {
        case 1:
            string_function();
            break;
            
        default:
            break;
    }
}

void string_function() {
    string user;
    cout << "Enter your first and last: ";
    getline(cin, user);
    cout << user << endl;
}


void menu() {
    int choice = 0;
    do {
    cout << "1. String functions" << endl;
    cout << "2. Array functions" << endl;
    cout << "3. Exit" << endl;
    cout << "Enter choice: ";
    cin >> choice;
    menu_act_on_choice(choice);
    } while(choice != 3);
    
}

//EXECUTE
int main() {
    menu();
}
```

Comment: The answer correctly identifies the first issue in your code. It's not the only one, however: try entering a word, rather than a number, at the menu prompt, and watch what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `cin.ignore();` before getline line.

Answer (score 4):

When you enter the menu choice which is read by

```
cin >> choice;
```

you ended that with the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key right?

That <kbd>Enter</kbd> key will be added to the input buffer as a newline. But `cin >> choice` will *not* read it, instead that happens with the `getline` call which reads it as an empty line.

The simple solution is to [ignore](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore) all input until (and including!) the newline after getting the menu choice.

```
cin >> choice;
cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```